# How to place image in a surface

Tags: uv, node-editor

[image: IMAGE PLACEMENT]

[image: NODE SETUP]

hi guys, I'm a newbie in blender and I just want to ask how to map and image/graffiti in surfaces that already has texture in it where there is X MARK (see image attached)I have my node setup also attached. I tried the uv maps(below the vertex group) but I dont know how it works,I also tried overlaying using mixRGB node but it maps to every surface that has concrete.I cant control it

Comment: Watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISEwqNHqe4

Comment: Could you post a .blend file?

Comment: thank you for the respond. im sorry.my question wasnt clear, its a 3drender image, i wasnt planning for animation yet.

Comment: my blend file is 127mb,but ill make a more simple version,i'll post it after its done.

Comment: @Allen 127mb is not a problem at all! Be sure to pack your images.

Comment: im from the philippines and the internet connection here is super slow.at least here in my place, so 127 mb would take too long, however i posted a simpler version though.

Answer (score 3):

A mix RGB node will work fine:

[image]

Use the alpha from the image on top for the fac input. You may need to try reversing which image is on top for best results.

Comment: http://www.4shared.com/rar/mBOMonCdce/test.html here i have a test version, i used the  color and the alpha and it seem working  because i have one side  with one circles .but the other side has circles map into them as well

Comment: another thing this is that. when i scale the side with one circle i ended up scaling the cobblestone texture too, instead of just scaling the circle

Comment: @Allen I can't download from that site, try here: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ Free, no account :D

Comment: @Allen You need to have different mapping nodes for each of them.

Comment: oh sorry :)
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34435
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/83922

Comment: The blend appears to be corrupted, I keep getting odd dialogs. Have you tried using the nodes in the example?

Comment: corrupted?should i upload the .blend1 file,maybe because i havent pack the 2 other images used.any way you could just replace it, right?,

yes i tried the nodes method you showed me but the image are mapping all over the, i just want to be on one plain

http://www.pasteall.org/pic/83923

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34436 here i packed them,

Comment: The blend seems to work perfectly? What is the issue?

Comment: yes but, the circles shows in every pplain that has concrete texture, i just want the circle to be on the left side

Comment: @Allen You have to stop it from reapeating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110019/stop-image-texture-from-stretching-blender